# .Net 6 dataverse client sdk error could not load type System.Runtime.Serialization.IDataContractSurrogate

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dataverse

Recently we have started a c# project using .Net 6.0. My team intended to use the
**Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client** sdk to connect to **dynamics 365 crm** for our development. However, when we hit the error as shown in image 1 below. May i know is it the SDK does not support .Net 6.0 yet?

[image: error image]

Comment: The Dynamics 365 only suppoert .NET 4.6.2  while  I worked for it one years ago 
reference:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/visual-studio-dot-net-framework?view=op-9-1

Comment: You may check this [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client#supportedframeworks-body-tab)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found the answer. Do not install the `Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies` library. That will resolve the issue.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I also found this to be the root cause of my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client sdk to connect to dynamics 365 crm

works with .net framework 4.6.2
or .net core 3.1

[MS Docs](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/dataverse-service-client-is-now-generally-available/)

[MS Github](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerPlatform-DataverseServiceClient)

Comment: There is a great Library on github which allows you to use the serviceclient for onpremise to. https://github.com/Data8/DataverseClient

Answer (score 0):

The `Dynamics 365` support .NET 4.6.2 in general

take a look here [Starting with the Dynamics 365 for Customer Engagement apps version 9.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/visual-studio-dot-net-framework?view=op-9-1)

In the [NuGet page](https://Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client), can know that it is support net462, net472, net48, netcore3.1

image from Nuget
[image]

**BUT** I will recommend you use the `.Net framework 4.6.2` in your application. To prevent unpredictable problem